# Call appropriate script based on url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call appropriate script in other php pages based on url ie:

sitename.com/sitepage?script1 > This would call script in script1.php

sitename.com/sitepage?script2 > This would call script in script2.php

sitename.com/sitepage?script3 > This would call script in script3.php

Etc (if nothing than run nothing)

Below I can read pathname after ?. I know how to call script based on get element. How to you run script in php based on url (without specifying if url is xxxxx)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var pathName = window.location.pathname;     
var pageName = pathName.substr( pathName.lastIndexOf("?") + 1 );
    )}
```

An example of the intention is:

url sitename.com/sitepage?script1 is opened
script on this page reads ?script1
now any script in script1.php is run

Comment: I would probably suggest `/sitepage#script1` instead.  Then you can just reference `window.location.hash`

Comment: Whats this gotta do with php?

Comment: thanks but using the # tag alone won't run the script from another php e.g sitepage#script1 > script1.php

Comment: I'm really confused now.

Comment: and the content of each script would replace the whole page or do you just want the php result loaded in the page as javascript ?

Comment: just want the result loaded for example if script1 was alert() i would want sitename.com/sitepage?script1 to alert

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it would open you up to script injections very easily, but this would be how I would add scripts based on URL.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var scriptLocation = window.location.search.substring(1);
  $(document.body).append($("script").attr("src",scriptLocation));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work (perhaps I've done it wrong or explained it wrong), it just adds a "/" between  "sitepage" and ?script1 (ie becomes "sitepage/?script1"). The result I wanted was it to see script 1 parameter (or others) and load script inside script1.php

Comment: Ummm, You'll need to do some .htaccess work for that.  Because I'm I don't think it will map it to the right file if you add an extra `/`.